# Implementation of a bottom sliding drawer

Tags: android

I want to include a drawer that slides up (using gestures) over the main activity in my app, but I don't know how I would implement this.

I've tried searching, but it seems as though Sliding Drawer was deprecated in **API 17**. I do not want to use third party libraries.

How should I go about this? Will a fragment with custom animations work?

Comment: What you mean is sort of like a Bottom Sheet. So go ahead you know what to do next.

Comment: @AlphaQ Yeah, sort of! I didn't know what to search for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the design support library to help you achieve this.

There's more on [the blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) but essentially you would be using a `BottomSheetBehavior` on a `CoordinatorLayout` (the root `ViewGroup` of that layout).

Comment: I used this, thank you. But I ran into one issue. I have an edit text in my bottomsheet, and when it is clicked on to insert text, the edit text does not get pushed up above the keyboard. Essentially, you can't see what you are typing. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @user5724753 I'm not sure to be honest - `EditText` widgets don't usually get used in bottom sheets. I also haven't tried it out myself yet so I'm not sure. You might find another answer on SO to help you. Do accept this answer if you have found it useful though. :)